# Pivot/Unpivot SQL Result Set Column Names into Separate Column

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a result set something like this:

| Username | Birthday | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Jan 23 | Male |

I would like to convert it to something like this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Username | Tom |
| Birthday | Jan 23 |
| Gender | Male |

I've been told Pivot/Unpivot was what I was looking for, but I can't find any info on pulling the column names.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use unpivot clause like below :

```sql
select *
from Your_Table t
unpivot (
 value for name in (
  Username as 'Username'
, Birthday as 'Birthday'
, Gender as 'Gender'
 )
)
;
```